# Wordpress Theme: Responsive Menu-bar Stops when theme installed on web server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am building a site for a client, He  requested I build just the Front-Page of the site then leave the other part of his selected theme theme the same .

I have done exactly that with the Wordpress installed on my PC using the header and footer from the selected theme .

Now, when I upload this theme to the web server of my client the responsive top menu bars that adjusts automatically and overlay the content when scrolled suddenly stopped working 
Please what should I do to stop this 
Its driving me crazy

I have deleted all other themes installed on the site as well as pre-installed plugins. I made sure that my new style and Js files has been properly linked to

Comment: if you remove any front page specific CSS, does the problem go away?

Comment: @suspectus Yes, I just tried and it does go away when i remove the bootstrap css but i got lots of my classes from there. Please what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***easy option*** is if the theme uses bootstrap, check that you are using the same bootstrap version as the theme.

If the theme does **not** use bootstrap, you should check if it uses some other "grid" CSS framework, and apply your changes using the grid system that the theme uses. You are sure to have problems if two CSS grid systems are applied to the same page. Bootstrap is an example of a "grid" type CSS framework.

You could try encasing your changes in a div something like this: 
`<div class="my_base_class">` and then prefix all your CSS changes with that class. But you would have to be careful not to interfere with the current CSS of the theme.

e.g.

```
.my_base_class .container {
   /* CSS code */
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thinks it uses normalize css